# Regex PHP part of string

Tags: php, regex, partial

I cant get my regexpression to work in php. It works in javascript (vuejs):

```
(?<=.+: )(.*)
```

I have this string:

```
NL: abcdef
```

and i would like to get

```
abcdef
```

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: A simple `(?<=: ).*` (or `(?<=: )(.*)` if the match needs to be in a capturing group like the original one) would work here, but we'd need more samples.

Comment: Okay, but the problem is that i have alot of different strings, where one is `NL: ` and the other `EN: `, `US: `, etc

Comment: So? Sounds like lookbehind for a colon (and space) should work fine? If not, can you post more examples for which that wouldn't work?

Comment: thank you! That did the trick :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this using PHP/PCRE, one is to skip the preceding string using `\K`

```
[^:]+: \K(.*)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nzaQsL/1/)

If you can add an anchor to the beginning of the string, even better: `^[^:]+: \K(.*)`

Comment: BTW: You said you used `(?<=.+: )(.*)` in JavaScript. However, this only works in Chrome v62+ (i.e. browsers supporting ECMA2018) but not in other major browsers because the lookbehind is not available in many JS' Regex flavor.